# Remove href containing specific text part

Tags: jquery, contain

I need to remove href for the links containing "ext" text

```
<a id="ctl00_" href="http://www.ext.com/aktiq" target="_blank">Akti</a>
```

I can't get it working

```
$("a[href]:contains('ext')").remove();
$("[href]:contains('ext')").remove();
$("href:contains('ext')").remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.removeAttr()` to remove attributes from elements.try this:

```
 $('a[href*="ext"]').removeAttr('href');
```

To replace with empty href:

```
 $('a[href*="ext"]').attr('href','');
```

Comment: Stop copy-paste, Started with `$("a:contains(ext)").removeAttr('href')`

Comment: @Satpal: thats not copy paste. i misunderstood the question at first.

Answer (score 2):

Use [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("a[href*='ext']").removeAttr('href');
```

Your code looks for `anchor` elements with `href` attribute and contains the text `ext` in it like `<a href=..>..ext...</a>`

Comment: I need to remove only href.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi you can use `removeAttr()` in that case

Comment: I was little confused about that. Will that remove the entire attribute? or will it clear only its value?